# Make pdf text recognizable python

Tags: python, pdf, text, text-recognition

I am combining a set of images (PNG's converted from PDF's - this step is a must in my case) into a PDF, but after that the text in them is not recognizable anymore. The quality is excellent, but the problem persists.

Is there a way to make such files text recognizable (I hope this is a term)?

Comment: The text in a pdf is store separately from images. You will need to copy the text from the pdf as well.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Indeed, I came to learn about OCR shortly after I posted the question.